# Samba: When I try to delete a file I get - jcifs.smb.SmbException: The system cannot find the file specified?

Tags: spock, samba, jcifs

I got a test where I'm trying to delete a file or all files in a folder after I connect to a smb server

```
def fullPath ="smb://XXXXX/XXX/XX/qa/"  
def smbFile = new SmbFile(fullPath, new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("","USERNAME","PASSWORD") )  
println ("SMB files -" +smbFile.listFiles())
```

> > this returns 
> >     `SMB files -[smb://XXXX/XXX/XX/qa/xyz.csv]`

Now if I run

```
smbFile.delete("xyz.csv")
```

> > The file is deleted but I get  -
> >     `jcifs.smb.SmbException: The system cannot find the file specified.` -
> >     and my test fails

Comment: figured it out, sorry to ask and answer my own question

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this out,if I used this instead
    smbFile.listFiles().each {(it.delete())}

Guess asking the question made me think it over more.